# Transaction-aware POJO in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-integration, pojo

I'm implementing a custom Transformer using a POJO (actually, a POGO) that is basically a text transformation service.

I'd like to make it "aware" of the transaction it belongs to and, at the end of the transaction, invoke a method if the whole transaction succeed and another one if the transaction rollback.

Any hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is called `TransactionSynchronization`. But I'm not sure that you should worry about such a low level and their is would be enough for you just to `try...catch` the TX stuff.

Even if it is POJO (or POGO ?) you configure it as a `<transformer>` (`@Transformer`) anyway. This kind of component in Spring Integration has `<request-handler-advice-chain>` (`adviceChain`) option to insert any `Advice` implementation around the `handleRequestMessage` method invocation.

For your purpose you can do that like this:

```
<transformer>
   <request-handler-advice-chain>
       <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <beans:property name="onSuccessExpression" value=""/>
            <beans:property name="onFailureExpression" value=""/>
       </beans:bean>
       <tx:advice>
           <tx:attributes>
               <tx:method name="*" />
           </tx:attributes>
       </tx:advice>
   </request-handler-advice-chain>
</transformer>
```

Where the TX semantics will be wrapped with that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` invoking the desired operation on the TX result, which is based in our case on the fact of `Exception` on TX rallback.

More info about `<request-handler-advice-chain>` you can read from the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

Comment: thanks a lot Artem! that was exactly was I was looking for! (PS: the G in POGO stands for Groovy :D)